# Add logic to delete method in Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, forms, controller, sinatra

I have been learning Sinatra for a couple of days now so I am still quite new. I am simply created a notes application and have added a delete function within the app.

Here is my Controller:

```
# Will display title of all notes
get '/' do
  @notes = Note.all
  erb :index
end

# Will display content within selected note
get '/:id' do
  @note = Note.where(id: params[:id]).first
  erb :note_description
end

# Will delete item from notes.
delete '/:id' do
  Note.delete(params[:id])

  redirect '/'
end
```

Here is my view with html/erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <p><a href="/">Return to Notes</a></p>

  <h1><%= @note.title %></h1>
  <p><%= @note.content %></p>


  <form onsubmit="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the following note?')" action="/<%= @note.id %>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

As you can see, I have created a `delete` button and have a pop-up on submit when you click it. This will simply verify if the user really wants to delete the object. What happens though, is no matter what I click the item will be deleted and I will be redirected to the home page. I want to add logic where the app will only delete and redirect me to home page if the user clicks okay. If they click cancel nothing should happen. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` from the event handler itself, so the attribute will look like:

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the following note?')"
```

Currently the return value of `return` is being returned *to* the event handler, but the handler itself is returning `true` (or at least not `false`).

(The current recommendation seems to be to avoid inline event handling like this though.)

Comment: nice find! That seemed to be the issue. I didn't know that I had to return it.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this behavior because the client is doing a POST, not a DELETE.

HTML forms only know how to do GET and POST. They cannot do PUT or DELETE. One way you can make it work is by using an AJAX call.

If you are using JQuery, you can set the `method` to DELETE. Here is the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

You will need to create the URL: `/1` for example. And you need to handle the success and failure cases. Perhaps set the location on success, and display an error on failure.

EDIT: According to Matt's comment below, `_method` param replaces the HTTP method. Even though this works, I don't think it is a good practice. It would be better to use the HTTP DELETE method.

Comment: Sinatra uses the [method override middleware](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb), which checks the hidden `_method` input and routes the request to the corresponding method in the app. So in this case although the browser uses `POST`, the Sinatra app will actually see the request as if it were a `DELETE`.